# Redirect URL using rewrite rules- https://hostname/en/<content-page> to https://hostname/en/<storename>/content-page>

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

**Redirect dynamic URL for below example** :

> https://hostname/en/content-page
>    to
>    https://hostname/en/storename/content-page

**content-page is the dynamic parameters Like-**

> https://hostname/en/grocery/vegetables?fetchFacets=true#facet:&productBeginIndex:0&facetLimit:&orderBy:&pageView:grid&minPrice:&maxPrice:&pageSize:&
>    to
>   https://hostname/en/storename/grocery/vegetables?fetchFacets=true#facet:&productBeginIndex:0&facetLimit:&orderBy:&pageView:grid&minPrice:&maxPrice:&pageSize:&

OR

> http://hostname/en/electronics?fetchFacets=true#facet:&productBeginIndex:0&facetLimit:&orderBy:&pageView:grid&minPrice:&maxPrice:&pageSize:&
>    to
>   http://hostname/en/storename/electronics?fetchFacets=true#facet:&productBeginIndex:0&facetLimit:&orderBy:&pageView:grid&minPrice:&maxPrice:&pageSize:&

add */storename* or */en/storename* in dynamic URLs

Comment: Looks interesting, but you did not ask any question...

Comment: How to redirect URL from https://hostname/en/content-page to https://hostname/en/storename/content-page
Note: content-page will be dynamic page, i want to add storename token after en token and before dynamic content-page

Comment: How to redirect URL from (https://hostname/en/content-page) 
to  (https://hostname/en/storename/content-page)
Note: 
content-page will be dynamic page, i want to add storename token after en token and before dynamic content-page

Comment: Please read about "How to ask a question" here on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  Please note that we are not here to do your work for you. SO is _not_ a free coding service. If you want someone else to do your work for you, then hire and pay someone for that. To receive help here you need to show your own effort, post the code you yourself implemented so far and you need to point out a specific issue with your code you fail to solve yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just put /en/ in your pattern and then substitute it with an appended storename. Add this to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ https://hostname.com/en/storename/$1 [R=301,L]
```

That will redirect as you've asked in your examples.